# pattern to allow everything other than comma, double quotes and slashes?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

What should the regex be for pattern attribute if i would like to allow any characters other than comma, double quotes and front and back slashes. Thanks for help.

```
pattern="^[^'\\"]*"
```

Comment: Do you expect your result to be a string with those characters skipped? 
`var pattern = /[^\/\\\,\"]/gi`

Comment: yes but that doesnt work. how can i write in the format pattern = "[^,]+"

Comment: this works to prevent comma, pipe and slash  pattern="[^,|/]+". But how can i prevent double quotes?

Comment: i would like to use in html tag attribute.

Comment: Escape it `pattern="^[^'\\\"]*"`

Answer (score 0):

try using "^[^,'\"/]+" This prevent comma single quote double quote back and front slash

instead of "^[^'\"]*"

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
pattern="[^,/|\\x22]+"
```

This will prevent comma, slash, pipe and double quotes in the string.